# Using CASE in Teradata, but only change some values

Tags: sql, case, teradata, case-when

I have a variable in my database that I want to change name on with CASE - WHEN-THEN but I want the variable to keep the values if the WHEN statement does not match.
How I wrote it:

```
(CASE 
WHEN Variable_name EQ ANY ('AA','AB','AC') then 'AA'
END)
```

I want my other results in Variable_name to be what they already is.
My data looks something like this:

```
Variable_name   Count
AA              2
AB              1
AC              5
BA              7
CA              5
```

And I want it to look like:

```
Variable_name   Count
AA              8
BA              7
CA              5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a `GROUP BY` query using the `CASE` expression you described to us.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Variable_name EQ ANY ('AA','AB','AC')
         THEN 'AA' ELSE Variable_name END AS Variable_name,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN Variable_name EQ ANY ('AA','AB','AC')
         THEN 'AA' ELSE Variable_name END;
```

Note that the answer given by @jarlh is ANSI compliant, because it does not put derived expressions into the `GROUP BY` clause.  But most databases do not enforce this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `EQ ANY` simply use `IN` and add an `ELSE`. And in Teradata you can use a `GROUP BY 1` to shorten it :

```
SELECT
   CASE 
      WHEN Variable_name IN ('AA','AB','AC') THEN 'AA'
      ELSE Variable_name
   END AS VariableName
  ,COUNT(*)
FROM mytab
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the select with case expression part up in a derived table. Then GROUP BY its result:

```
select Variable_name, count(*)
from
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Variable_name EQ ANY ('AA','AB','AC')
             THEN 'AA' ELSE Variable_name END AS Variable_name
    FROM yourTable
) dt
GROUP BY Variable_name
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you desire aggregate your query with a SUM function after your case statement.

```
-- test table
 CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt_variable  ( 
  variable_name VARCHAR(2)
  ,Cnt  INTEGER
  ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS; 

  -- seed test table 
  INSERT  INTO vt_variable ('aa',2);
  INSERT INTO vt_variable ('ab',1);
  INSERT INTO vt_variable ('ac',5);
  INSERT INTO vt_variable ('ba',7);
  INSERT INTO vt_variable ('ca',5);

  -- query 
 SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN Variable_name EQ ANY ('AA','AB','AC') THEN 'AA' ELSE variable_name
  END var 
  ,Sum(Cnt) AS sum_cnt
 FROM vt_variable 
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```